# Pre-compile pug templates and save access to htmlWebpackPlugin.options

Tags: webpack, pug-loader

I decided to shift from `ejs` to `pug` as a template engine in my webpack projects. And what I need is pre-compiled static output (either in dev or in prod mode). Plus, I need to pass data to templates through the compilation process, and I use custom options of `htmlWebpackPlugin` for it. The project structure is as follows:

```
root
|--package.json
|--webpack.configs // .dev.js, build.js
|--data.json
|--layout.pug
|--app
|--|--index.js
|--|--views
|--|--|--index.pug
|--|--|--includes
|--|--|--|--nav.pug
|--|--|--|--footer.pug
|--assets
|--|--(styles, images...)
```

The first way I found and tried is to pass data to the entry point (compile locals at `index.js` and insert them to the page via `innerHTML =`). This way is absolutely not suitable for me as I need 100% pre-compiled static output without runtime HTML insertions. And then the fun begins...

For example, I need to create navigation. I have the schema of navigation as follows:

```
module.exports.nav = [
        {
          text: 'Home',
          href: '/'
        },
        {
          text: 'Offers',
          href: '/offers.html'
        },
        {
          text: 'Subnav Parent Test',
          isSubnavTrigger: true
        },
        {
          text: 'Subnav Item',
          href: '/test.html',
          isSubnavItem: true,
          subnavParent: 'Subnav Parent Test'
        }
      ]
```

and pug partial for this `app/views/includes/nav.pug`:

```
nav.navbar(role="navigation", ariaLabel="navigation")
  .container
    .navbar-brand
      a.navbar-item(href="/")
        img(src="/assets/images/logo.png", alt=title)
    .navbar-menu(id="navbar-menu")
      .navbar-start
      .navbar-end
        for link, index in nav
          //- TODO: isActive
          if !link.isSubnavTrigger && !link.isSubnavItem
            a(href=link.href, class="navbar-item")= link.text
          else if link.isSubnavTrigger
            .navbar-item.has-dropdown.is-hoverable
              a.navbar-link= link.text
              .navbar-dropdown
                - var parent = link.text
                - var dd = nav.filter(_item => _item.subnavParent === 
parent)
                each dd_link in dd
                  a.navbar-item(href=dd_link.href)= dd_link.text
```

that partial is included in common layout `layout.pug`:

```
- var { title, nav } = htmlWebpackPlugin.options;
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= title + 'Pug Webpack Test'
    block metas
  body
    header
      include ./app/views/includes/nav.pug

    main
      block content

    footer  
      include ./app/views/includes/footer.pug
```

with the hope that `app/views/includes/nav.pug` will interpolate `nav` variable.

So I've discovered 2 cases: use `module -> rules -> loader` and inline loader to HTMLWebpackPlugin.

The 1st. `webpack.config.js` settings:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[path][name].html', 'pug-html-loader?pretty&exports=false']
      }
      //...
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    //...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './layout.pug',
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'siteTitle',
      nav: nav  // required somewhere at the top of the file
    })
  ]
}
```

With this case I fail to pass options from `htmlWebpackPlugin` into templates. As mentioned in `layout.pug`, I try to destruct `title` and `nav` fields from options and get compilation error: `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`.

The 2nd case. `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      // Removed PUG loaders
      //...
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    //...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '!!pug-loader!./layout.pug', // <- inlined loader
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'siteTitle',
      nav: nav  // required somewhere at the top of the file
    })
  ]
}
// by the way, in case of EJS I've been using exactly this approach
// and it worked out pretty well with partials
```

This approach perfectly compiles `layout.pug` with options taken from `htmlWebpackPlugin`, **until it does not contain included partials**. And I need to pass my `nav` to corresponding partial and to render nav from there. And partial start to throw errors into compilation as if it doesn't understand `pug` and needs loader:

```sh
  ERROR in ./app/views/includes/nav.pug 13:12
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    |       .navbar-start
    |       .navbar-end
    >         for link, index in nav
    |           //- TODO: isActive
    |           if !link.isSubnavTrigger && !link.isSubnavItem
     @ ./app/views/index.pug (c:/_npmg/node_modules/pug-loader!./app/views/index.pug) 4:514-543
```

I'm totally in mess. I do not want to draw back to `ejs`, but if I will not find an answer, it seems that I will have to.

Thanks forward.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED.**

The answer consists of 2 conclusions:

1. **Use appropriate loader.**

   The only loader that fits to my needs is `pug-loader` (not `pug-html-loader` and not chain of multiple loaders). Reference is [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/747#issuecomment-316960902), but in 2 words:

   > `pug-loader`: returns a function
   >
   > `pug-html-loader`: returns a string, so it's static and no options can be pass through

   So, the final `webpack.config.js` settings regarding this are:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      test: /\.pug$/,
      use: [
        {loader: 'pug-loader'}
      ]
      //...
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    //...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './layout.pug', // <- NOT inlined loader
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'siteTitle',
      nav: nav  // required somewhere at the top of the file
    })
  ]
}
```

2. **Partials do not inherit variables from layout that partial have been required from.**

   So, as I want to use data from `htmlWebpackPlugin.options`, I have to declare variable for this data *not* in common layout file, *but* in partial itself:

```
// app/views/partials/nav.pug
- var { nav } = htmlWebpackPlugin.options

nav.navbar(... and the other code you've seen above)
```

In case of someone face this problem, this is 100% working approach.

Answer (score 2):

I want to notify OP about his solution but i can't comment.

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `pug-loader` can work well together. Instead of using :

```js
// webpack.config file
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './layout.pug',
      filename: 'index.html',
      myContent: 'loremp ipsum'
    })

// app/views/partials/nav.pug
- var { myContent } = htmlWebpackPlugin.options
p= myContent
```

you can use the following syntax :

```js
// webpack.config file
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: './layout.pug',
   filename: 'index.html',
   templateParameters: {
       myContent: 'loremp ipsum'   
   }
})

// app/views/partials/nav.pug
p= myContent
```

It works with all pug engine features and we get more readable templates.

Comment: Thank you, will try to use this approach.